# simple visual webpart, is not rendering the controls

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I created a simple visual webpart with this html

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LinkButton.ascx.cs" Inherits="xx.xxxxDMS.WebParts.VisualWebParts.LinkButton.LinkButton" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenModalPopup(pageUrl) {
        var options = { url: pageUrl, width: 900, height: 300 };
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
    }
</script>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LnkButton" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then in the code behind, I added 3 properties. After I edit the properties with a text link and an url, I dont see the LinkButton rendered. Am I missing something? Please notice that its SP 2013.

I was going to try this solution: http://www.tfsconsulting.com.au/visual-studio-2012-sharepoint-2013-visual-web-part-project-template-is-buggy/

But I noticed that there is no ASCX file for my customwebpart in the control templates folder, so I guess this changed in 2013?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace xx.SP.xx.WebParts.VisualWebParts.LinkButton
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class LinkButton : WebPart
    {
        private string _LinkText;
        private Uri _Link;
        private Boolean _OpenModal;    

        [WebBrowsable(true), WebDisplayName("LinkText"), WebDescription("Text for the link"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), Category("xx - xx"),
        System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
        public string LinkText
        {
            get { return _LinkText; }
            set { _LinkText = value; }
        }

        [WebBrowsable(true), WebDisplayName("Link"), WebDescription("Link"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), Category("xx- xx"),
        System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
        public Uri Link
        {
            get { return _Link; }
            set { _Link = value; }
        }

        [WebBrowsable(true), WebDisplayName("OpenModal"), WebDescription("OpenModal"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), Category("xx- xx"),
        System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
        public Boolean OpenModal
        {
            get { return _OpenModal; }
            set { _OpenModal = value; }
        }

        // Uncomment the following SecurityPermission attribute only when doing Performance Profiling on a farm solution
        // using the Instrumentation method, and then remove the SecurityPermission attribute when the code is ready
        // for production. Because the SecurityPermission attribute bypasses the security check for callers of
        // your constructor, it's not recommended for production purposes.
        // [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
        public LinkButton()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            if (LnkButton != null)
            {
                LnkButton.Text = LinkText;
                if (OpenModal)
                {
                    LnkButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OpenModalPopup('" + Link.ToString() + "');");
                }
                else
                {
                    LnkButton.PostBackUrl = Link.ToString();
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try initializing those values with a default to start with - does that work? Then you can determine if its configuration, or the linkbutton that isn't quite working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint 2013 webparts work differently.
THere is no need to find the controls using the control templates, if you move the code from CreateChildControls to the page load it will work without any problem.